# Конвертировать миллисекунды в дни (часы, минуты)

Tags: python, дата

Скрипт на python для считывания показаний. Время работы показывает в миллисекундах, хотелось бы в часах и минутах. Наставьте на путь истинный, как и чем лучше сделать.

[image: Скрин скрипта]

Comment: Сокращайте вопрос, убирайте лишнее )

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите красиво, то можно так:

```
# pip install pendulum
import pendulum

ms = 4274483
print(pendulum.duration(milliseconds=ms).in_words())
```

> 1 hour 11 minutes 14 seconds

ну или так:

```
print(pendulum.duration(milliseconds=ms).in_words(locale="ru"))
```

> 1 час 11 минут 14 секунд

Answer (score 0):

например так:

```
timestamp = 12345678

hours = timestamp // (3600 * 1000)
minutes = (timestamp - hours * (3600 * 1000)) // (60 * 1000)
```